# How to handle API errors efficiently?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, redux-saga

When everything goes well it returns an object with `status: 'OK'`
If something goes wrong it returns `status: 'FAILED'`,
Due to this approach I need to handle errors in both the try and catch blocks, e.g.

```
try {
  const {data} = await axios.post(....);

  if(data.status === 'OK') {
    // do something and return 
  }

  //handle error
} catch(e) {
  // handle Error Again
}
```

As you can see I need to handle the errors two times. I am using redux-saga so I make another file for APIs and handle it in saga like this:

```
yield = ...my api

// then 

if (data.status === 'OK') {
  // do something and return 
}
```

and so on... My end goal is to keep my sagas clean. Is there any way in which I can call the API then check the status in the API file? It should go to the catch block of the saga so I would have to handle the errors in my catch block only?

My end goal would be like this

```
function* doSomethng() {
  try {
    yield callapi...
    //do something
  } catch(e) {
    // handle errors and even if the api status is 200
    // but it returns an object with status 'FAILED' it should come here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper function, that will add a check to the promise chain and throw on bad status.

```
const checkStatus = async (promise) => {
    const result = await promise;
    if (!result || result.status === 'FAILED') throw new Error('Request failed');
    return result;
}

function* doSomething() {
    try {
        yield checkStatus(callapi(...));
        //do something
    } catch(e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can also "hid"e the checkStatus call in the `callapi` function itself.